# S3 CloudFront React SPA returns 403 due to hashtag but cannot setup 403 error page

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, auth0, amazon-waf

Unfortunately, Auth0 adds a hashtag in the callback URL to single page style applications. See the example below.

`https://stage.domain.com/callback#access_token=...&otherQueryParam=...`

This returns a 403 error within my S3 and Cloudfront environment.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>...</RequestId>
<HostId>
...
</HostId>
</Error>
```

The solutions I have seen all over the internet involve creating an additional custom error handle configuration within **CloudFront** to redirect any 403 errors to 200 and render index.html.

However, I cannot do this because the **staging** environment **is only accessible behind a VPN** and there is a **WAF** rule that **blocks** all IP Addresses except the VPN. If I were to allow 403 it would render the **WAF** rule useless and publicly expose my staging environment.

Would like for my React SPA to be hosted within S3 for easy scalability, however, it is looking like I may have to spin up some sort of EC2 running Nginx.

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ..."
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::stage.domain.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What are some proposed solutions to this issue?

Comment: Did you find out any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup,

```
- WAF only allows access from a set of whitelisted IPs
- CloudFront Serves React Site from S3
- CloudFront Custom error response redirects 403 -> 200 and renders index.html
```

Any IPs outside of the whitelist who request the webpage receive a 200 response but the app does not render, only a whitepage is displayed.

I agree that it's not ideal for any non-whitelisted IPs to have any access at all but for now it works until I can find a better solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a better approach?